# Echo contents of a heading of one .org file in another

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to have contents of a heading of an `.org` file echoed in another `.org` file, so that the text in the second file would be updated automatically when the first file changes?

For example, suppose that we have `.org` files dedicated to branches of a company, as follows.

The contents of `new-york-branch.org`:

```
* Location       :location:
  New York   
* Director       :director:
  John Smith
```

The contents of `washington-branch.org`:

```
* Location       :location:
  Washington
* Director       :director:
  Ann Grey
```

Then we would somehow be able to compose a file `index.org` like this:

```
* Branches
** New York
   Director: John Smith
** Washington
   Director: Ann Grey
```

In the file `index.org` above, `John Smith` and `Ann Grey` are echos of the contents of `new-york-branch.org:director` and `washington-branch.org:director`, respectively. There will probably be some hidden text as well to specify these data sources. In any case, if Ann Grey is replaced by Susan May in `washington-branch.org`, the change will get reflected in `index.org` automatically. Please note that I am not looking for `#+INCLUDE`, since I would like the change to be reflected in `org-mode`, without the need to export.

Can this be done?

Comment: I like to use the org-id feature for jumping to/from locations within the same or different files.  If you do implement your own feature request, it would probably be a good idea to use a unique way of identifying the different locations instead of relying upon a word search since there may be more than one match using the latter method.  My recollection is that there is another thread that inquires about this feature and it seems like 4 to 6 months ago, but I'm not sure and haven't yet performed Google searches to locate the other thread.

Comment: I think this is called transclusion. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328515/iso-transclusion-in-emacs-org-mode for one approach to the solution. An alternative approach was discussed on the org mailing list: https://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg110355.html.

Comment: @JohnKitchin This should be a reply (you might want to discuss the pros and cons of the two approaches), unless my post should be marked as duplicate.